# Chances of contracting hook worm in Canada?

Tags: disease-transmission, parasites, geography, barefoot, hookworm

Hook worm is contracted through infected soil, feces, etc. If I am correct? Every website says developing countries are more at risk, but how at risk am I in Canada when I walk barefoot on trails and paths?

Comment: @Pills-N-Pillows: Do we really need a hookworm tag for only one question? The tag seems to specific to me, parasites should suffice.

Comment: @Narusan, it's about the future of Stack Exchange. This won't be the last question about hookworms. There are separate tags for tapeworm, ringworm, etc. -- just being consistent with the website. Parasites is a great tag, which is why I included it (it wasn't included in this question before), but it can be too broad if people in the future are researching hookworms specifically.

Comment: @PillsNPillows: Sorry, didn't know so many different worm-tags existed. Obviously if they do and we want to keep them, this one should be created for consistency. Maybe this should be addressed in [meta].

Comment: @Narusan, I hear ya! Maybe there needs to be categories within "parasite" section, and one of the categories can just be worms, etc. haha. I don't know! :) There's so many different types of parasites -- hard to say. But I get your point!